# Performing logic before adding model object and updating database in django

Tags: python, django

When I add an object through my `admin.py`, how do I perform extra logic before adding the object?

For example, I click `ADD MEDIA` button within my admin and add a media object:

[image]

Notice how under `Location` there is a value `Video Intro`. I want that value to appear only once. If it exists, change the other object have a `Location` value to `None`.

I want this logic to perform before adding the new model object. Now sure where to make changes and how to do so.

Here is the project structure:

[image]

Here is my `admin.py`:

```
class MediaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name", "file"]
    list_display = ("name", "media_type", "location", "url", "album", "display", "thumbnail", "filesize")

    def display(self, media_obj):
        return format_html('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (media_obj.file.url, media_obj.file.name))

    def filesize(self, media_obj):
        return self.convert_size(media_obj.file.size)

    def convert_size(self, size):
        if (size == 0):
            return '0 B'
        size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
        i = int(math.floor(math.log(size,1024)))
        p = math.pow(1024,i)
        s = round(size/p,2)
        return '%s %s' % (s,size_name[i])

    def thumbnail(self, media_obj):
        # pdb.set_trace()
        # location = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, media_obj.file.name)
        location = media_obj.file.url
        thumbnail_html = "<a href=\"{0}\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"{1}\" height=\"80\" /></a>".format(location, location)
        return format_html(thumbnail_html)


class MediaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Media

class AlbumInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Album

admin.site.register(Media, MediaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Album)
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Media(models.Model):
    LOCATION = (
        ("video_intro", "Video Intro"),
        ("logo", "Logo"),
        (None, "")

    )

    TYPE = (
        ("video", "Video"),
        ("gif", "GIF"),
        ("picture", "Picture"),
        ("audio", "Audio")
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(choices=LOCATION, default=None, max_length=500, null=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE, default=None)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Media"
```

Comment: You can override the `.save()` method in your `Media` model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Comment: If you want to do the check only on object creation add the condition `if self.pk is None:` to your checking code on `save`.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to customise the creation of a new instance of the model (i.e. a new record in the table), customise [the `save` method of the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save).

The `save` method is called to store the (new or modified) instance to the database. You can perform any other processing there to “hook” into that save event.

Answer (score 1):

[Use Unique Together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together) model meta, so you can be sure there will be only one video intro. No matter its been added via frontend or admin interface.

But I dont think this option does enforces dropdown menus.

Comment: unique_together will raise a validation error instead of rewriting the value of the other object to be None.